# Populating a Column in a Table Based on Count of Rows in Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables namely users and stock. User id (id) in table users is a foreign key constraint on column current_owner in the table stock. I want to update a column named holdings in users table based on count of rows where users.id  = stock.current_owner.  I tried the following query but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD holdings INT UNSIGNED AS (COUNT * FROM stock WHERE stock.current_owner = users.id)
```

I need help with this query.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  two queries

add the column using alter

```
  ALTER TABLE users ADD holdings INT UNSIGNED;
```

popolate the columns using Update based on a join between user and a subquery for count()

```
  UPDATE users 
  INNER JOIN (
    select current_owner, count(*) mycount
    from stock 
    GROUP BY current_owner
  ) t ON t.current_owner = users.id 
  SET user.holdings = t.mycount
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  A clarification  Would i have to run this query each time I want to update the holdings or would the column be updated each time there is a change of ownership in the stock table?

Comment: You must execute the update  each time you want  to update the holdings column .  (if you need  an automatic update  you should take a look at Store Procedure) ..

Comment: I got the following error while using the second query. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 't_owner = users.id
  SET user.holdings = mycount' at line 6

Comment: answer update. removed  wrong space between current_ owner .. .